# Ø in LEGO part names

Tags: piece-information

Many LEGO part names use a Ø character in the name, for example, Armor For Hand W/Ø 3.2 Shaft (28803) or Beam A 4M Ball/Cup Ø10.2 (90611).  Can anyone explain what the Ø means?

Comment: It's not a Ø or a ø, it's a ⌀.

Comment: It's not Swedish "crossed O", it's not Greek "capital phi", it's not even Cyrillic "Ef", it's a dedicated "diameter symbol".

Comment: @Agent_L: Swedish doesn't have Ø; they use Ö instead. Ø is used in Danish, however, which is more relevant for Lego.

Answer (score 27):

Ø is a pretty [standard notation for diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Diameter_symbol). So `w/Ø 3.2 Shaft` means the item has a shaft that has a 3.2(mm) diameter.

Answer (score 14):

To elaborate on hobbs's comment, that character should actually be [⌀, `U+2300` DIAMETER SIGN](http://unicodinator.com/#2300), the meaning of which should be self-explanatory.

The character you asked about was [Ø, `U+00D8` LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE](http://unicodinator.com/#00D8)

Of course, it's entirely possible that the wrong symbol was used by the person naming the part in the list you're looking at (perhaps due to poor unicode support, since `U+00D8` lies in latin-1, but `U+2300` requires utf8).

Comment: Or perhaps because Ø has its own key on most keyboards used in Billund.

Comment: http://fontmeme.com/images/danish-keyboard-550x183.png

Answer (score 0):

It's an international symbol, whose curious intersection between a line segment and a circle visually depicts the concept of a *"a measurement exceeding the diameter of a part by some 15%, I reckon"*.

Comment: This is completely incorrect.