# What is the name of the small pins that are used with small wheels / rims?

Tags: piece-information, terminology, wheel

I see that there are at least three different types of axles that can be used with LEGO wheels. I can name the first two — *Technic axle* and *Technic pin* — but I cannot name the third, which is like a Technic pin, but smaller.

Note that I've only seen it integrated into a larger part, such as a brick or plate, as shown in the image. I see that BrinkLink sometimes refers to parts like this as having "wheels holder" pins, but that seems to be a term that could apply to the first two types of axles as well.

Does a common and more precise name exist for this type of pin?

[image: Image of Lego element from brickset.com]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LEGO and others sometimes calls those pieces [a "bearing element"](https://brickset.com/parts/448826/bearing-element-2x2-single). This term however [is not limited to just that axle](https://brickset.com/parts/4211778/bearing-element-3x6).

LEGO's replacement parts service calls the holes they go into "HOLE Ø11" (possibly read "Hole Diameter 11"):

[image: HOLE Ø11]

The width of the axle is roughly equivalent to the width of a "bar", like [the 30374 piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30374#T=C) used for Lightsabers as such.

None of these names are particularly satisfactory, but I'm not aware of any better names.

Comment: Thanks. Is "Ø" a way of writing zero, or does it mean something else?

Comment: See https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8060/%C3%98-in-lego-part-names?rq=1 for an explanation on the diameter symbol.

Comment: And is "W" an abbreviation for the word "with?"

Comment: @EJMak I assume so, yes.